# Code for Updating page in WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

I need to use the same page for Updating my details.. can any one help me to design it..

**Here is my Design code of XAML for Adding data..**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,157,12,4" Grid.RowSpan="2">            
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,67,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="PersonalFullName"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="121,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="PostalAddress"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,197,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="City" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_city"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,178,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="AddressCity"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,259,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="State" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_state"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,237,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="AddressCountryShortName"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,324,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Country" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_country"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,302,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="AddressCountryName"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,386,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Web Site" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_website"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,361,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="Url"/>
    </Grid>
```

**My Button Click code is..**

```
Organization neworganization=new Organization();
 private void btn_add_organization_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                neworganization = populateOrganizationDetails();
                string organizationDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(neworganization);
                client.addNewOrganization(organizationDetails);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
         }
```

**populateOrganizationDetails()**

```
private Organization populateOrganizationDetails()
        {
            neworganization.name = txt_name.Text;
            neworganization.address = txt_address.Text;
            neworganization.city = txt_city.Text;
            neworganization.country = txt_country.Text;
            neworganization.website = txt_website.Text;
            neworganization.state = txt_state.Text;
            neworganization.region = txt_city.Text;
            return neworganization;
        }
```

Can any please help me to design the page for updating the details in same page..I would be more thank-full..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished my task and here i had updated my smple code..

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,157,12,4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListBox x:Name="editorg" Height="579" Width="456" ItemsSource="{Binding Organization}">

       <TextBlock x:Name="name_txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="0,78,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="22" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
       <TextBox x:Name="txtbx_name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="100,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" InputScope="Default" IsHitTestVisible="True" AcceptsReturn="True" />
       <TextBlock Name="Address_txt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="0,148,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" />
       <TextBox x:Name="txtbx_address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="100,118,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding  address,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" InputScope="AddressStreet"/>
    </Listbox>
</Grid>
```